# Cannot assign 128 to byte, why does it error out instead of overflowing?

Tags: java

Bytes in Java range from -128 to 127. If over 127 they overflow. So I assigned 128 to a `byte` variable to know how overflow work, but the compiler shows a error message: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte".

Why do I get a compiler error instead of it overflowing?

[image]

Comment: You have to explicitly cast. byte B = (byte)128; because 128 is out of range it is an int. javac is smart like that, and lets you assign smaller values.

Comment: Also, post code, not images of code. There really isn't any reason to paste an image in this instance.

Comment: overflow only happens during an arithmetic operation. You have coded an `int` literal, which cannot be safely cast to a byte without loss of data, so an explicit cast is required; during the cast, an overflow of a sort occurs.

Comment: Thanks @matt will improve the format next time. so you mean Java can not allow to assign over range number to a variable unless using cast? is my understanding right? thanks!

Comment: Right, `javac` the compiler will prevent you from assigning a value out of range. Your error is happening during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

javac will let you assign values within range to bytes. When you go out of range, the value needs to be explicitly cast.

```
byte b = (byte)128;
```

Would work with the compiler. To see overflow you might try

```
byte b = 127;
b += 1;
System.out.println(b);
```

> -128

The nuts and bolts can be found in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html). Java will do arithmetic as `int`, or `long`.

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 2;
//byte c = a + b; //fails because the operation is performed as an int.
byte c = (byte)(a + b);
```

Comment: hi @Matt, 
If I write like this, it still display error message: 


"byte B= 127;

B=B+1;

System.out.println(B);"

Can you help to explain? thanks a lot!

Comment: Subtle difference between what you wrote and what I wrote, b+=1; is ok. b = b + 1; is not ok, b + 1 is treated as an integer and you would have to cast. I'm actually surprised it works the way I wrote it, so I checked before posting. https://ideone.com/o7sNLU and if you change the += to b+1 it will fail as you have seen.

Answer (score 1):

A byte is an 8-bit signed integer value that can hold values between -128 and 127.

You can cast 128 into a byte `'byte b = (byte)128;'`, but then b will just equal -128 because of how twos-complement numbers work.

Answer (score 1):

Integer constants like 1, -32, 128, or 7654321 have `int` type in Java. Assigning an `int` value to a `byte` variable is simply not allowed. This is why you get the error `cannot convert from int to byte`. To get around it, you have to convert the int value to byte with a *type cast*, `b=(byte)128`.

The real question should be, why do you *not* get an error for this code?

```
byte b = 100; // !!!! ASSIGNING int TO byte !!!!
```

You don't get an error here because of this a [special "assignment conversion" rule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) that only applies for compile time constant expressions:

> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Type
`byte B = (byte)128;`

instead of `byte B = 128;`